# Hypernym for "trimester" and "quarter"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I am looking for a hypernym for *trimester* and *quarter*.

Comment: Please add the context to your question—as answers have shown, both ‘trimester’ and ‘quarter’ can be used to describe various different things, and a hypernym for them will differ depending on the context. For example, both ‘stage(s) of pregnancy’ or ‘academic terms’ could be correct answers in the right circumstances.

Comment: Actually I just found the core issue: In Spain there is the word 'Cuatrimetre' which means a period of 4 months. I was in the confusion that quarter was the translation of that word.

Comment: No, a quarter is (among other things) _three_ months, just like ‘trimester’. It is the same word as _cuarto_ in Spanish, so it just means ‘one fourth’; i.e., 15 minutes (if relating to an hour), three months (if relating to a year), etc. This doesn’t change the fact that a three-month period can still be a subdivision of many different things, and therefore, the question needs context to be answered. If you asked in Spanish what the hypernym for _cuarto_ is, should it be ‘fractions’, ‘living spaces’, or ‘time units’? It could be all three in different contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

timespans ?  periods ?

(warning: I am non native speaker and too low rep to comment)

PS if you downvote, please explain why, so I can learn. Thank you Shyam and all!

btw the title and body of the question has been edited and no more exacly reflects the original question, imho

Comment: "Periods" is fine. "Timespans" doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Peter Shor. Hi. Deeply honored. I am going to frame this :-)

Comment: Please restrict the answer to the answering the question - and put comments (e.g. questions about downvotes, and comments about edits) into comments.

Answer (score 6):

**Academic terms**.

If you are looking for a *hypernym* for semester, trimester and quarter, then *academic term* is the answer.

Comment: You know, I read the *term* part there completely the wrong way.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_term

Comment: In my case, there is no academic context. The context is an invoicing schedule, where invoices can be grouped by quarters or trimesters. I am looking for a word to refer to said things.

Comment: @Nerian You say "quarters ***or*** trimesters". If they are both 3 months, what's the difference? I'm asking because the word is not in common use in the UK, in either academic or other contexts, except for the 3 trimesters of a pregnancy.